# Add multiple customer attribute fields in Magento registration form

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute, registration

I am trying to add 2 customer attribute fields in my Magento registration form.

The input names are the same in the `register.phtml` as in the `install-1.0.0.php` file. However I think there is something wrong in the installer file, because **only the first attribute is saved** (`is_privacy_statement`).

Here is my code from the installer file:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "is_privacy_statement",  array(
    "type"      => "int",
    "label"     => "Privacy Statement",
    "input"     => "checkbox",
    "position"  => 120,
    "required"  => true,
    "is_system" => 0
));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "is_general_terms",  array(
    "type"      => "int",
    "label"     => "General Terms",
    "input"     => "checkbox",
    "position"  => 121,
    "required"  => true,
    "is_system" => 0
));

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "is_privacy_statement", "is_general_terms");

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";

$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1);

$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

I have no idea why is not saved the second attribute too.

Comment: Try this : `$attribute1 = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "is_privacy_statement"); $attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer",  "is_general_terms");` because that `getAttribute` method have 2 param only.

Comment: I have added updated code in answer Please review it and accept if it work for you, so it will help to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$attributeArray = [
    [
        'code'      => 'is_privacy_statement',
        'label'     => 'Privacy Statement',
        'position'  => '1020'
    ],[
        'code'      => 'is_general_terms',
        'label'     => 'General Terms',
        'position'  => '1021'
    ]
];

foreach($attributeArray as $attributeCreate)
{
    $installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->addAttribute(
        "customer", $attributeCreate['code'], array(
            "type"      => "int",
            "label"     => $attributeCreate['label'],
            "input"     => "text",
            "visible"   => true,
            "required"  => true,
            "default"   => "1",
        )
    );

    $attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", $attributeCreate['code']);

    $used_in_forms = array();

    $used_in_forms[] = "adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[] = "checkout_register";
    $used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_edit";

    $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", $attributeCreate['position']);

    $attribute->save();
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

**Note:** input type are changed, as per "[On customer register got an error message: “Cannot save the customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/229321/65808)”" because got errors with `checkbox` and/or `boolean` type, and the code a little bit optimised.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I thought this will work, it seemed to make sense, but it is still saving the first attribute only.

Answer (score 0):

So your code should be like this after changes:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "is_privacy_statement",  array(
    "type"      => "int",
    "label"     => "Privacy Statement",
    "input"     => "checkbox",
    "position"  => 120,
    "required"  => true,
    "is_system" => 0
));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "is_general_terms",  array(
    "type"      => "int",
    "label"     => "General Terms",
    "input"     => "checkbox",
    "position"  => 121,
    "required"  => true,
    "is_system" => 0
));
$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";

$attributeIsPrivacyStatement = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "is_privacy_statement");



$attributeIsPrivacyStatement->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1);

$attributeIsPrivacyStatement->save();

$attributeIsGeneralTerms = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "is_general_terms");

$attributeIsGeneralTerms->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1);

$attributeIsGeneralTerms->save();


$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thank you. It is not working. I have double checked the names and deleted the cache. Still the first attribute only is saved.

Comment: check that `is_general_terms` attribute is exist in database.

Comment: It does exist only the `is_privacy_statement` attribute.

Comment: remove your module from `core_resource` and remove the first attribute and install again OR try with `upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php` add with the second attribute.

Comment: I have removed the data as per your comment and now "Cannot save the customer."

Comment: what error you getting and update updated code in question.

Comment: `Cannot save the customer.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78639/discussion-between-kunj-and-gravuj-miklos-henrich).

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich Please accept my answer if it resolved your attribute issue, so it will help to others.

Comment: I will accept if so, can't tell yet if resolved. Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not working. I am sorry. I have already posted another question with the error. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code for create account in add customer custom field and using with **patch/data** so you can add multiple customer custom attribute with multiple file so you can easily handle from there.

I've created for business name like this

1. setup/patch/data

   ```
    <?php
    namespace Praas\CustomerAccountRegistration\Setup\Patch\Data;

    use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

    class AddBusinessNameAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
    {
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductCollectionFactory
     */
    private $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var Attribute
     */
    private $attributeResource;

    /**
     * AddPhoneAttribute constructor.
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param Attribute $attributeResource
     */

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Attribute $attributeResource,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        $this->addPhoneAttribute();
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }
    /**
     * @throws AlreadyExistsException
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function addPhoneAttribute()
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer:: ENTITY,
            'business_name',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Business Name',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => 0,
                'visible' => 1,
                'user_defined' => 1,
                'sort_order' => 999,
                'position' => 999,
                'system' => 0
            ]
        );
        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'business_name');
        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'adminhtml_checkout',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function revert()
    {

    }

    /**

     * {@inheritdoc}

     */

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    } }
   ```

2. view/frontend/templates in additional.phtml

   ```
    <div class="field business_name">
    <label class="label" for="businessname">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Business Name')) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="business_name" id="business_name" value=""
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Business Name')) ?>" class="input-text">
    </div>
   ```
3. customer account file in layout customer_account_create.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Praas_CustomerAccountRegistration::additional.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
 </body>
</page>