# On customer register got an error message: "Cannot save the customer"

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, customer-session, registration

Couple of hours ago the registration worked well. Suddenly it is not working anymore. Reverted back my code changes and the problem still persists. What I've only done is to clear the cache. To get a concrete error message instead of `Cannot save the customer` exception, I did the following temporary trick:

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
        ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
}
```

Since Magento is masking the raw PHP error, I did the following change to the above code:

```
->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.' . $e->getMessage()));
```

Now, my complete error message looks like this:

```
Cannot save the customer.Warning: include(Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Checkbox.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I am not sure what is causing this issue and why happened suddenly.

Couple of other details:

- yes, the `Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Checkbox.php` file is missing on my local environment, and I don't know why
- the `Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Checkbox.php` file exists on the repo I am gettig the files (Git)
- I downloaded a new Git repo, the problem still persists
- I don't know if it is some write permission issue or it is due to compilation (I think here must be the problem, but I don't know what to do...)
- Only cache deletion was made before the error via the admin panel

Comment: You need to add your own renderer for this because Magento not providing input type checkbox.

Comment: On the dev server, not configured by me, it is working. Something else must be the problem. I run my local environment on a virtual machine, ubuntu, php7.0

Comment: I mean you need to add your own renderer for those attributes because we have type checkbox and Magento not providing that input type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution! Kind of a workaround, but it works ...

```
Cannot save the customer.Warning: include(Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Checkbox.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

The above error message means that very probable (99.99%) you are in an attempt to add a `checkbox` *custom attribute field* to the user register form. Just like in my case. Magento 1.9.x does not have a renderer for checkboxes at `Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Checkbox.php`

Since I did not had a clue how to write my own renderer, as per @kunj suggestions, I've tried a workaround solution.

To have a better image about adding custom customer attribute fields on the customer registration form, you can read the following two tickets:

- [Add new field in magento(1.9) customer registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/65760/65808)
- [Add multiple customer attribute fields in Magento registration form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/229189/65808)

**Solution**

In the `install-1.0.0.php` file I've used to following code:

```
$attributeArray = [
    [
        'code'      => 'is_privacy_statement',
        'label'     => 'Privacy Statement',
        'position'  => '1020'
    ],[
        'code'      => 'is_general_terms',
        'label'     => 'General Terms',
        'position'  => '1021'
    ]
];

foreach($attributeArray as $attributeCreate)
{
    $installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->addAttribute(
        "customer", $attributeCreate['code'], array(
            "type"      => "int",
            "label"     => $attributeCreate['label'],
            "input"     => "text",
            "visible"   => true,
            "required"  => true,
            "default"   => "1",
        )
    );

    $attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", $attributeCreate['code']);

    $used_in_forms = array();

    $used_in_forms[] = "adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[] = "checkout_register";
    $used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_edit";

    $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", $attributeCreate['position']);

    $attribute->save();
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

The trick is the declaration of the inputs: `"input"    => "text"`, so not `select` or `boolean`.

In the `register.phtml` file I've used:

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="is_privacy_statement" id="is_privacy_statement" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="is_privacy_checkbox" class="form-control required-entry" />
    <label for="is_privacy_checkbox" class="required">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('adatvedelem') ?>" target="_blank">
            <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Privacy Statement')) ?>
        </a> <em>*</em>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="is_general_terms" id="is_general_terms" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="is_general_checkbox" class="form-control required-entry" />
    <label for="is_general_checkbox" class="required">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('altalanos-szerzodesi-feltetelek') ?>" target="_blank">
            <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('General Terms')) ?>
        </a> <em>*</em>
    </label>
</div>
```

The `text` input fields are hidden. The `checkboxes` are visible.

In order to make this code work, will need to following workaround with jQuery:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var is_privacy = $('#is_privacy_statement'),
            is_terms = $('#is_general_terms'),
            is_privacy_checkbox = $('#is_privacy_checkbox'),
            is_terms_checkbox = $('#is_general_checkbox');
        is_privacy.hide();
        is_terms.hide();
        $(is_privacy_checkbox).on('click', function() {
            if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                is_privacy.val('1');
            } else {
                is_privacy.val('0')
            }
        });
        $(is_terms_checkbox).on('click', function() {
            if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                is_terms.val('1');
            } else {
                is_terms.val('0')
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**What is happening?**

You are registering a text input, but for user friendly purpose you are willing to show checkboxes on the customer registration form. You will hide the text inputs, which values are passed to the database, and their values are handled by the according checkbox statuses controlled by jQuery.

**Drawback:**

In the administration panel the values `0` or `1` are saved into text inputs, but if you are not confortable with this, it can be changed with a similar aproach with jQuery.